# React this.props.children not being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create the whole navigation as a component for my webapp (ie header, navigation and wrapper for the page) like so:

```
const Navigation = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        console.log(this.props.children);

        return (
            <div id="authenticated">
                <div id="header">...</div>
                <div id="left-menu">...</div>
                <div id="page">

                    {this.props.childen}

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This is how I use it in `Dashboard.jsx`which uses the component:

```
import { Navigation } from '../../components'

const Dashboard = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
       return (
            <Navigation>
                <p>Hello</p>
            </Navigation>
        );
    }
});
```

It renders the component (the nav, header,...) but doesn't render the `<p>hello</p>`. The console log does show me the `<p>hello</p>` as a react object but it just doesn't render it on the page!

Any ideas?

PS: I've seen this and it's not the issue: [React ES6 | Child Component not being rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668632/react-es6-child-component-not-being-rendered)

Comment: In the provided code, you're not using the `Navigation` component, you are using the `AuthenticatedLayout`

Comment: @nem035 Thanks for pointing it out it is right in my code though, I was just trying to simplify it here. Corrected now.

Comment: the next step is to inspect in the DOM and see what is actually there. It could be getting rendered but just not visible because of a css rule

Comment: You have a typo: `childen` instead of `children`. I guess your username is fitting ;)

Comment: @nem035 Thanks! I feel stupid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You got a typo,  `this.props.childen` should be `this.props.children`

```
const Navigation = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div id="authenticated">
                <div id="header">...</div>
                <div id="left-menu">...</div>
                <div id="page">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

[full working example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/46236/)

Comment: working for me. i done same mistake...thank you QoP